# Is there a way to hide this AES URL php

Tags: php, encryption

Is there a way to hide the AES URL ? from fiddler and softwares alike? It's fine if they see the FINAL url when they scan it, I just dont want them to see the Encryption. Because with this script, using view-source, you can't view its source...But when scanning with fiddler. It shows its content from the Header(Location: xxx

I hope, I was clear enough in what I want to do and someone Please can help me out. Thank you.

```
<?php
/**
 * XML Protecting
 *
 */
  include("uye/baglanti.php");
$diger_eleman = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$kullanici_adi = $_GET["username"];
$parola = $_GET["pass"];
$sorgula = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uyeler WHERE kullanici_adi='{$kullanici_adi}' and parola='{$parola}'") or die (mysql_error());
$uye_varmi = mysql_num_rows($sorgula);
        if( strstr($diger_eleman, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0') AND $uye_varmi > 0)               {

 header("Location: 35kKpUNRq6RZB/iFzcImnHaT4+RCndIfNYWvG6tJDqw="); #IS THERE A WAY I CAN HIDE THIS URL/CONTENT? FROM APPEARING ON FIDDLER!
 exit;
}

else
{

echo str_repeat("<br>", 8)."<center><img src=uye/images/hata.gif border=0 /> Do you need anything? EMail ME at xxxx@gmail.com</center>";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Security through obscurity is not a valid security tactic.

Comment: If you have this script on a public server, you have more serious problems than the location being shown.

Comment: 1) What is an "AES URL"? Is it a URL encrypted with some AES key? If so, how is the AES key transmitted to the client or does the client need to know it at all? 2) Your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use prepared statements instead. 3) This extension that you use is deprecated and removed in PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

From the basic premise: **[Encrypting URL parameters is a bad idea](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)**. Your URL scheme is almost certainly vulnerable to chosen-ciphertext attacks.

However, the point of *encryption* is that the ciphertext can be made public without revealing the original message. Why you want to obfuscate ciphertext is unclear. You probably have an incorrect threat model of the problem you're trying to solve.

Do you *need* to store data in a URL, if it's sensitive? Can't you place it in a session variable to be read during the next HTTP request? That's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to **make some info unavailable** on the client side is to **not send it**.